# teechart labels style lost after zoom

Tags: asp.net, teechart

I am using teechart 
version `TeeChartNET2014_4.1.2014.08120`
on asp.net webform with .net framework 4.0

Problem shows when I use zoom tool.
Especially this setting:

```
Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelStyle.Text;
```

The setting works correctly, but after I zoom, it is lost.
All settings remain ( marks, titles, colors, even angle for 
`Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle` - set to 90 ), but this one is definitely lost, even when I return to default view.
( zooming was prepared according to tutorials and examples found in program group of teechart product )

Answer (score 1):

I have made a simple example where I have used a zoom combined with TextLabels and the example works without problems using TeeChart for.Net build 4.1.2015.05140. I have attached below the code I have used:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Steema.TeeChart.Chart ch1 = WebChart1.Chart;
        System.IO.MemoryStream tmpChart = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        if (Session["ch1"] == null)
        {
            //setup Chart
            if (ch1.Series.Count < 2)
            {
                ch1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line());
            }


            if (ch1.Tools.Count < 1)
            {
                ch1.Tools.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ZoomTool());
            }
            ch1.Series[0].Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 199, 26);
            ch1.Series[0].FillSampleValues(36);
            ch1.Aspect.View3D = false; 
            ((Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ZoomTool)ch1.Tools[0]).ZoomPenColor = Color.OliveDrab;
            ((Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line)ch1.Series[0]).Pointer.Visible = true; 
            ((Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line)ch1.Series[0]).Pointer.Pen.Visible = false;
            ((Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line)ch1.Series[0]).Pointer.HorizSize = 2;
            ((Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line)ch1.Series[0]).Pointer.VertSize = 2;


            //AddSeriesText
            TextLabels(ch1);

            //export Chart to a MemoryStream template
            ch1.Export.Template.Save(tmpChart);
            //save template to a Session variable
            Session.Add("ch1", tmpChart);
        }
        else
        {
            //retrieve the session stored Chart
            tmpChart = (System.IO.MemoryStream)Session["ch1"];
            //set the Stream position to 0 as the last read/write
            //will have moved the position to the end of the stream
            tmpChart.Position = 0;
            //import saved Chart
            WebChart1.Chart.Import.Template.Load(tmpChart);

            //check whether zoom request is being sent
            CheckZoom(WebChart1);
        }
    }

    private void CheckZoom(Steema.TeeChart.Web.WebChart wChart)
    {
        System.Collections.ArrayList zoomedState = (System.Collections.ArrayList)Session[wChart.ID + "Zoomed"];
        zoomedState = ((Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ZoomTool)wChart.Chart.Tools[0]).SetCurrentZoom(Request,
            zoomedState);
        if (zoomedState == null)
            Session.Remove(wChart.ID + "Zoomed");
        else
            Session.Add(wChart.ID + "Zoomed", zoomedState);
    }

    private void TextLabels(Steema.TeeChart.Chart chart)
    {
        chart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelStyle.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < chart.Series[0].Count; ++i)
        {
            chart.Series[0].Labels[i] = chart.Series[0].XValues[i].ToString();
        }
        chart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
    }
```

Then, I have tested if the problem appears using the code above and the TeechartFor.Net build 4.1.2014.08120 and I have detected a problem with zoom in that version. Maybe it is related by the fixed bug [id1201](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1201). Therefore, I would like suggest you test the latest TeeChartFor.Net version and check if the problem is fixed for you, too. You can download the trial version from [here](http://steema.com/evaluation).